# Flip a matrix fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I want to flip my matrix up side down. Such that T(1,1)=C(2,1)

I have made this program and I found a the code that is supposed to do that online that is `C=T(2:1:-1, :)` But when try to get the value C(1,1) that should be 3 I get 1.3533635457363350E-306. How do you flip a matrix such that up becomes down?

```
program main


implicit none
  integer iMax, jMax
  double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: T,C

double precision x, dx,f,L2old,L2norm

integer i, j,n


 allocate(T(0:2, 0:2))
 allocate(C(0:2, 0:2))


T(1,1)=1
T(1,2)=2
T(2,1)=3
T(2,2)=4

write(*,*) T(2,2)

C=T(2:1:-1, :)

Write(*,*) C(1,2)


end program main
```

Comment: To start from: you allocate matrices `T` and `C` to be of 3x3 size and not 2x2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you allocate matrices of the right size, then everything should work as expected.

For instance, this program

```
program main
  implicit none

  double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: t, c
  integer :: i

  allocate (t(1:2, 1:2))
  allocate (c(1:2, 1:2))

  t = reshape([1, 3, 2, 4], shape(t))
  do i = 1, 2
    write (*, *) t(i, :)
  end do
  write (*, *) ""

  c = t(2:1:-1, :)
  do i = 1, 2
    write (*, *) c(i, :)
  end do
end program main
```

produces the following output

```
   1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000
   3.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000

   3.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000
   1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000
```

---

Or, if you indeed wanted to work with 3x3 matrices, then the mistake is in the line `C=T(2:1:-1, :)`. It should be `C=T(2:0:-1, :)`.

```
program main
  implicit none

  double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: t, c
  integer :: i

  allocate (t(0:2, 0:2))
  allocate (c(0:2, 0:2))

  t = reshape([1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9], shape(t))
  do i = 0, 2
    write (*, *) t(i, :)
  end do
  write (*, *) ""

  c = t(2:0:-1, :)
  do i = 0, 2
    write (*, *) c(i, :)
  end do
end program main
```

Output:

```
   1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000
   4.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000
   7.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000        9.0000000000000000

   7.0000000000000000        8.0000000000000000        9.0000000000000000
   4.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000        6.0000000000000000
   1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000
```

---

Be careful with counting elements of arrays. [Off-by-one errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) might be quite difficult to debug, so better always start counting from 0 or always from 1. And to be on the safe side always traverse arrays with the help of `lbound` and `ubound` intrinsics, rather than using explicit bounds as it is done above:

```
  do i = lbound(t, dim=1), ubound(t, dim=1)
    write (*, *) t(i, :)
  end do
```

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating 3 x 3 arrays (index ranges 0 - 2, inclusive).  You assign values to only four of the nine elements of array `T`, and then assign a 2 x 3 slice of that array to `C`.  That's invalid because the array expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator has different shape from the one on the left-hand side.

Furthermore, your choice of array elements to write belies continuing confusion about the dimensions of the arrays involved.  If you allocate `T` with dimensions 0:2, 0:2 and then flip it vertically, the element of the result corresponding to `T(2,2)` would be `C(0,2)`.

There are several possible ways to correct the code.  Among the more likely:

- If you want to continue with the dimensions you are now using, then the expression for the flipped array would be `T(2:0:-1, :)`.
- If you want 2 x 2 arrays with index ranges 1 - 2, inclusive, as would be consistent with `C=T(2:1:-1, :)`, then allocate the arrays appropriately (e.g. `allocate(T(2, 2))`).